# HTML to PDF Converters for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdf-generation

I am in search of a **FREE HTML to PDF converter for .NET** which preferably takes an HTML page and renders it into a PDF document.

The HTML page (when printed) will **most often be more than one page**.  I know of ABCPDF, but from a quick overview, it appears it just wants to convert a single page of HTML and doesn't handle multiple pages well.  I could be ignorant of its capabilities as I haven't put very much research into ABCPDF yet.  The only other one I have gently used is iText, but that seems like it may become very complicated for the application I need.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations.  If you know of one that does cost per license, but does exactly what I need, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for the quick replies! I will review the options and mark the solution I go with as the answer.

Comment: FYI for future passer-byers - ABCPDF is NOT free...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT:** ABCPDF no longer offers a free option unless you can satisfy their requirements of either being a *Worthy Cause* or a *Worthy Individual*.  More details here: http://www.websupergoo.com/free-license.htm

<s>ABCPDF will handle multiple pages, as stated in [this link](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-9.htm) - "You can even have HTML flowed between multiple columns over multiple PDF pages."</s>

I've used it extensively and found it to be pretty good.

Either that or [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) if you're after open source options.

If you've got some money to spend, then have a look at [Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx).

Comment: Please note that iText/iTextSharp are free for open source projects only. There is [probably expensive] commercial license for other cases, though.

Comment: I am using ABCpdf for multiple pages too, and it works well.

Comment: @Bobrovsky: Good point, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Paged HTML Example can be found here:
http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/4-examples/13-pagedhtml.htm

Comment: Just a note for others: ABCPDF isn't free - but there is a (laborious?) promotional programme to get a free license.

Comment: Why suggest ABCPDF when it is clearly not free? Please see: http://www.websupergoo.com/free-license.htm

Comment: @VBobCat You may have missed the date on the answer... it's from over 5 years ago.  It's a while ago now, but IIRC WebSuperGoo used to offer a free option if you provided credit for their library on your page.

Answer (score 8):

Just implemented something similar in one of my projects using wkhtmltopdf (webkit based)
 I'm rendering views or partial views to strings, writing them to temp html file and sending starting the exe in a new System.Diagnostics process..

The pdf's look absolutely awesome, it works with external css sheets and everything.

Comment: +1 It will also **execute javascript** with the full HTML DOM supported.  wkhtmltopdf is Very Nice.

Comment: Not only will it execute javascript, but it allows for javascript delays and ajax calls to complete before taking the snapshot.  Awesome, awesome product.  And the price is right!

Comment: Forgot to mention -- it even honors CSS page-breaks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a free one, but we use [Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) for .Net to generate PDFs from files hosted in SharePoint through a custom [document converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms518493%28v=office.12%29.aspx). HTML is one of the supported formats.

Note: I have no affiliation with Aspose, I've just been pleased with the component they provide.

Answer (score 2):

ITextSharp can do this for you. http://itextsharp.com/

This answer has some links to some code..
[Convert HTML file to PDF file using ITextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392778/convert-html-file-to-pdf-file-using-itextsharp)

Comment: Yep. See: http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/itextsharp-simplify-your-html-to-pdf-creation/

Answer (score 1):

Winnovative HTML to PDF converter is what I've used for years. Great tool, good documentation.

http://www.winnovative-software.com/

Comment: This one is not free.

Comment: @Josh `Please let me know if you have any recommendations. If you know of one that does cost per license, but does exactly what I need, let me know.`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact fit, but [this should work for you](http://brandonzeider.me/2010/microsoft-net/convert-word-to-pdf/) with a little modification if you have MS Word installed on the machine executing the code. All you should have to do is open the HTML as a Word document (since MS Word can open HTML). It's a free way to do it if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you - this would be simple, but I am trying to go without having to install Word on the server.

Comment: No problem - when I was looking, I didn't think there was a library out there that didn't require an installation, and since we had licenses for MS Word already, we opted to just install MS Word. Good luck!

Comment: It fulfills my needs and is surprisingly quick even though I'm generating a dozen PDFs at a time. Thanks @BrandonZeider!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to: https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp