# Saving Word DOCX files as PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, openxml, docx

I'm using openxml to create Word DOCX files. I'd like to save these documents once they are created as PDF files. Is there a way I can do this in openxml? I assume the answer is no. If it is no, is there a recommended library or tool I can use to save / print DOCX files as PDF (programatically, in .NET)? I looked at sharpPDF (PDFSharp), and it seems this library is only for generating PDFs from scratch, not saving DOCX as PDF.

Can I somehow Print to an installed PDF printer, either Cute PDF or the PDF printer built in to Windows 7 in a fully automated fashion?

Update: Looking for free with non-viral license, and preferably doesn't require additional installations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do this with Word automation. You need to have word installed.

```
var TheDocument = TheWordApp.Documents.Open(docName);

TheDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(
            docName.Replace(".docx", ".pdf"),
            Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, 
            OptimizeFor: Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, 
            BitmapMissingFonts: true, DocStructureTags: false);

((Word._Document)TheDocument).Close();
```

Comment: Microsoft Interop? Yes, this does indeed work. I was hoping to do it without having to have Word installed. This might be my path forward if there isn't a free way to do it without other dependencies.

Comment: @cellik:does it work with the application configured in IIS?

Answer (score 2):

To get from DocX -> PDF you need something that can render a DocX file and provides a PDF export/save capability.  Needless to say, there aren't that many tools that can render DocX (Word, OpenOffice/LibreOffice and some other licensed products mentioned below). Depending on your runtime limitations/requirements, you could try:

1. to use MS Automation to get Word to load the docx and save as PDF.
2. tools that sit on top of OpenOffice (JODConverter/Docmosis) to do the conversion.
3. try embedding other document libraries (Aspose, Windward)

I'm not sure about the auto print requirement sorry.

Comment: You can use docx4j's PDF output in a .NET environment via IKVM, but I'd suggest trying it first in a Java environment to see whether it suits your needs

Comment: For #1, are you referring to the MS OFfice Interop library?

Comment: @StealthRabbi - yes sorry for the poor terminology.

Comment: Updating my earlier comment, Plutext now has a commercial docx to PDF converter; try it at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used the [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx) suite of tools for this in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5513946/54762. It's not free, but you can demo it before you buy it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/productions/articles/word2pdf.htm) VBScript and it works well. It works in the background (opens the docx and saves as PDF using "Save/Export as PDF" option). Check the system requirements listed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

We produce WordGlue .NET which is a generic WP layout engine that can handle doc/docx.

It's completely managed and can be used to export to a variety of formats like image, XPS or (with the help of a PDF library such as ABCpdf) PDF.

I work on the ABCpdf .NET software component so my replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's just what I know. :-)